# How can I listen for all events dispatched to some object?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, events

Using [`addEventListener`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29) I can register callbacks to be invoked if a specific kind of event is dispatched to some object. How can I have my callback invoked if *any* event is dispatched to the object?

Comment: By "ANY" event, do you mean just those that you have assigned a listener to?

Comment: @bigp: I mean any object whose type is `Event` or a sub-class of `Event`.

Comment: Ok, but I mean do you only want to get your "universal" callback to trigger on the Events you've listened for? Or all possible events dispatchable by a Flex component? As far as I know, I don't think there's a way (for the latter) unless you mess around with the code of the Flex components directly.

Comment: @bigp: I'd like the latter. I'm trying to understand which events exactly (and in which order) are being receveived by some Flex control when the user performs some specific actions (e.g. which events are received by a `mx.controls.TextInput` control if the user clicks it and types `Ctrl+A`).

Comment: I'm not totally certain of this, but you may be able to achieve this with flash.trace.Trace (a special undocumented object, see: http://blog.sangupta.com/2011/08/magic-of-flashtracetrace.html) You could sort through the traced data possibly to collect that information. Sorry I don't have time to put an example together though.

Comment: When would this be helpful? From what I see this wouldn't do you any good anyway.  Imagine catching all events from Stage.  then you catch one.  Now, to do anything intelligent with it, you still have to say if(event.type == MouseEvent.CLICK){//do stuff} so you still need to know the type to respond intelligently... so you might as well add all the listeners you want to do something for.

Comment: @JasonReeves: I want to do one of the few things which is plausible to do with *any* event: printing it. I'm trying to write some sort of 'debug' helper which shows me the object tree and (this is the important part which I didn't see anywhere else yet) the events being dispatched to some selected object.

Answer (score 2):

You can override `dispatchEvent`, something like following:

```
public class UniversalDispatcher extends EventDispatcher {

    override public function dispatchEvent(event:Event):Boolean {
        if (event is UniversalEvent)
            return false;
        var uEvent:UniversalEvent = new UniversalEvent();
        uEvent.subEvent = event.clone();
        var res:Boolean =  super.dispatchEvent(event);
        super.dispatchEvent(uEvent);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Create custom event, which will contain original one:

```
public class UniversalEvent extends Event {

    public static const UNIVERSAL:String = "universal";
    public var subEvent:Event;

    public function UniversalEvent(type:String = UNIVERSAL, bubbles:Boolean = true, cancelable:Boolean = false) {
        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var ud:UniversalDispatcher = new UniversalDispatcher();
ud.addEventListener(UniversalEvent.UNIVERSAL, onUniversalEvent);
ud.dispatchEvent(new Event("blabla"));
ud.dispatchEvent(new Event("test"));
ud.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));

private function onUniversalEvent(event:UniversalEvent):void {
    trace("Event dispatched: " + event.subEvent.toString());
}
```

TRACE:

```
[trace] Event dispatched: [Event type="blabla" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
[trace] Event dispatched: [Event type="test" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2]
[trace] Event dispatched: [MouseEvent type="click" bubbles=true cancelable=false eventPhase=2 localX=NaN localY=NaN stageX=NaN stageY=NaN relatedObject=null ctrlKey=false altKey=false shiftKey=false buttonDown=false delta=0]
```

Comment: This doesn't help if the object to be monitored for events is not written by me (e.g. a `mx.controls.TextInput` or so).

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say: what if the object to be monitored for events isn't even instantiated by me. Say, the stage object itself.

Comment: Well, that's a problem, seems to be impossible

Answer (score 0):

If you do have control over each event listeners added via "addEventListener", you could do something like this:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.utils.Dictionary;

var label:TextField;
var wrap:Wrapper;

label.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, wrap.universalFunc( MouseEvent.CLICK, onLabelClick ));
label.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, wrap.universalFunc( MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onLabelMouseDown ));
label.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, wrap.universalFunc( MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onLabelMouseUp ));


class Wrapper {
    private var _eventTypes:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    public function universalFunc( pEventType:String, pCallbackFunc:Function ):Function {
        _eventTypes[pEventType] = pCallbackFunc;
    }

    private function universalListener(e:Event):void {
        var callback:Function = _eventTypes[e.type];
        if (!callback) {
            return;
        }

        //Do whatever common behavior you want here:
        // ...

        //Pass the event to the callback method:
        callback(e);
    }
}
```

Or, much cleaner and less redundant:

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.utils.Dictionary;

var label:TextField;
var wrap:Wrapper;

wrap.listen( label, MouseEvent.CLICK, onLabelClick );
wrap.listen( label, MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onLabelMouseDown );
wrap.listen( label, MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onLabelMouseUp );

class Wrapper {
    private var _eventTypes:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

    public function listen( pDispatcher:IEventDispatcher, pEventType:String, pCallbackFunc:Function ):void {
        _eventTypes[pEventType] = pCallbackFunc;

        pDispatcher.addEventListener(pEventType, universalListener);
    }

    private function universalListener(e:Event):void {
        var callback:Function = _eventTypes[e.type];

        if (!callback) {
            return;
        }

        //Do whatever common behavior you want here:
        // ...

        //Pass the event to the callback method:
        callback(e);
    }
}
```